docker command not found by systemd service
I am on nixos, but this shouldn't be relevant for this problem.
I created a systemd service which starts a docker container (open-webui). Even before logging in, the container starts and the web ui works completely fine, but according to the logs of this systemd service, this should not be the case:
$ journalctl -b 0 -u open-webui-custom.service
Aug 22 11:51:13 <pc-name> systemd[1]: Starting Start up Open WebUI Server...
Aug 22 11:51:13 <pc-name> systemd[1]: Started Start up Open WebUI Server.
Aug 22 11:51:13 <pc-name> open-webui-custom-start[3036]: /nix/store/igwwyxj9qznw0bcylwf5f5f1pyrgl2w1-unit-script-open-webui-custom-start/bin/open-webui-custom-start: line 3: docker: command not found
Aug 22 11:51:13 <pc-name> systemd[1]: open-webui-custom.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug 22 11:51:13 <pc-name> systemd[1]: open-webui-custom.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

The generated .service file:
[Unit]
After=docker.service docker.socket
Description=Start up Open WebUI Server

[Service]
Environment="LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/nix/store/..."
Environment="PATH=/nix/store/w1iq3315z63558j04gnlzdd2yk1v1hfz-coreutils-9.5/bin:/nix/store/ajymwgc23snyw48wvkapw4qjggsi2vbw-findutils-4.10.0/bin:/nix/store/7adzfq6lz76h928gmws5sn6nkli14ml6-gnugrep-3.11/bin:/nix/store/d58flzaagmfb5pyvmknly4cnws45nc80-gnused-4.9/bin:/nix/store/mhq3m0gm80w8xxkbbkhds2gcm2k7y4fd-systemd-256.4/bin:/nix/store/w1iq3315z63558j04gnlzdd2yk1v1hfz-coreutils-9.5/sbin:/nix/store/ajymwgc23snyw48wvkapw4qjggsi2vbw-findutils-4.10.0/sbin:/nix/store/7adzfq6lz76h928gmws5sn6nkli14ml6-gnugrep-3.11/sbin:/nix/store/d58flzaagmfb5pyvmknly4cnws45nc80-gnused-4.9/sbin:/nix/store/mhq3m0gm80w8xxkbbkhds2gcm2k7y4fd-systemd-256.4/sbin"
Environment="TZDIR=/nix/store/g3nif4n7a4gmrng4xgihkd4l8q04hh3p-tzdata-2024a/share/zoneinfo"
ExecStart=/nix/store/igwwyxj9qznw0bcylwf5f5f1pyrgl2w1-unit-script-open-webui-custom-start/bin/open-webui-custom-start 
Group=root
Type=exec
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

And the script which gets run by this service:
#!/nix/store/4bj2kxdm1462fzcc2i2s4dn33g2angcc-bash-5.2p32/bin/bash
set -e
docker container rm open-webui && docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /mnt/860Evo/open-webui:/app/backend/data -e OLLAMA_BASE_URL=http://192.168.178.184:11434 --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main

According to my understanding of systemd services After should ensure that the docker command is accessable. I am sure that systemd does not try to start my service before  docker.service anddocker.socket because these also use WantedBy=multi-user.target
My next idea was, that root is not in the docker group. But using User=root Group=docker leads to the same outcome. Even changing User to run the service as my own user - which definitely has access to the docker command - does not work.
I suppose that this service is still called before the docker daemon is ready to use. What do I do to solve this problem?

I know that there is services.open-webui for nixos, but I want more control over how the docker container is run and what permissions it has + I want to switch to rootless docker in the future.

You set PATH to only have directories for ... coreutils, findutils, gnugrep, gnused and systemd ... which one of this is supposed to have the docker command?

I added docker's bin and sbin to PATH, but the docker command is still not found. I dont think this is the problem, since somehow these commands are actually executed - the web ui thats served by the container is accessible

The problem seems to be something different. I removed the systemd service entirely until this is solved but noticed that open-webui still starts (from journalctl)

Is this using docker compose? You can set a container to start on boot using docker compose, iirc.

Thanks to muru 's latest answer I had a look at the docker run command and realised that my blindly copy-pasted command docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /mnt/860Evo/open-webui:/app/backend/data -e OLLAMA_BASE_URL=http://192.168.178.184:11434 --name open-webui --restart always ghcr.io/open-webui/open-webui:main would register the container to automatically start at each boot. Thats why the webserver was running despite the systemd service failing.
In the systemd service, I added Requires=docker.service and the path to the docker binary and I removed docker.socket from After. Instead of using docker run I switched to docker start - now everything is working :D
Thank you muru 
